# Como remover um array de dentro de outro array filtrando os que tiverem o valor X em uma chave especifica em Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou iniciando no Node.js e tenho um pouco de dificuldade em lidar com array/json, estou em processo de aprendizado ainda.

Supondo o seguinte array de arrays:

**Array base que deverá ser filtrado:**

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "nome":"Jonh Doe",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "nome":"Mary",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "nome":"Tom",
      "city":"CO",
      "status":"Married"
   },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "nome":"Mark",
      "city":"MI",
      "status":"Divorced"
   },
   {
      "id": 5,
      "nome":"Carl",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
]
```

Precisaria salvar em uma variável este mesmo array porém somente onde a chave ***city*** for igual a ***NY***. Pesquisei sobre `.map`, `.filter`, `.reduce`, `.indexOf` porém não consegui chegar a um resultado. Como eu poderia atingir o seguinte resultado:

**Array filtrado somente de NY:**

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "nome":"Jonh Doe",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "nome":"Mary",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
   {
      "id": 5,
      "nome":"Carl",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, acho que não pesquisou bem, porque `filter` e `map` podem fazer isso, de uma maneira até bem simples:

```js
var array = [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "nome":"Jonh Doe",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "nome":"Mary",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "nome":"Tom",
      "city":"CO",
      "status":"Married"
   },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "nome":"Mark",
      "city":"MI",
      "status":"Divorced"
   },
   {
      "id": 5,
      "nome":"Carl",
      "city":"NY",
      "status":"Single"
   },
];

var novoArray = array.filter(x => x.city == "NY");
console.log(novoArray);
```

Nesse exemplo usei `filter`, que deve receber uma function ou expressão que avalia cada elemento do array, e retorna `true/false` para cada elemento, e os elementos onde a condição for `true` são retornados. Ou seja, os elementos onde `city == "NY"` são retornados, devolvendo um novo array só com esses elementos.

Comment: Bem explicado Ricardo. Os exemplos que eu via era sempre `var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` e filtrando um numero especifico ou algo assim, achei que teria grandes diferentes pra remover o array inteiro com base em uma chave. Eu achei que o `.filter` ia remover apenas aquela chave e não o array inteiro. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade não é só Node.js é JavaScript no geral. Como você já mencionou, dá para resolver em uma linha só com `filter`, supondo que seu array inicial se chama cidades:

```js
cidades.filter(i => i.city === "NY")
```

Versão mais detalhada:

```js
cidades.filter(cidadeIteracao => {
  if (cidadeIteracao.city === "NY") {
    return cidadeIteracao;
  }
});
```